# Extracting the first page content of a word document using the page height

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-poi, openxml, document

I need to get first page content from a word document via parsing the openxml of the document.I understand that word document is reflowable and i cannot extract a particular page's content because there is no information about implicit page break in the openxml.
But using page height information and formatting specification such as font size, image height, number of enters pressed in a page I think i can extract the first page content.
But I couldn't  understand in what units the size is specified in openxml.

```
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="00BE0591" w:rsidRPr="006534F8">
        <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
        <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440"     w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
        <w:cols w:space="720"/>
        <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
```

Can anyone help me in creating a logic to get first page content based on the page height calculation ?

Comment: What is the "height" of the first page? The height is the height of the paper format, isn't it?

Comment: I have edited my question title to be more clear.Height is the height of the paper format.There is no information about implicit/soft page break in the openxml of the document.Word assigns page number dynamically based on calculation of font size ,number of line breaks and other formatting options.All i want to know is what calculation does it use to do this.